# How to get data from response if you receive an error?

Tags: reactjs

How do I get a backend error if I get a 404?
Here is my code:

```
export const myRequest = async (body: params) => {
  try {
    const result = await publicInstance.get('users', {
      params: body,
    });
    const { data } = result;
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error.message, error); // How to get data from response?
  }

  return {};
};
```

Comment: What is `publicInstance`? What does `error` print? There is too much info missing here

Answer (score 0):

You will get the statusCode in the response, which you can track. Based on the status code you can put your customized error message.

```js
export const myRequest = async (body: params) => {
  try {
    const result = await publicInstance.get('users', {
      params: body,
    });
    const { data } = result;
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
  
  if(error.statusCode == 404)
  error.message = "Unable to reach server at the moment. Please try again."

  console.error('Error:', error.message, error); 

  }

  return {};
};
```

Comment: How would you know what `publicInstance` is?

Comment: 4** status code is irrespective of publicInstance/server.

Comment: I doubt it. It depends on the implementation of `publicInstance.get` as it's not further described it could be anything, even something that doesn't even throw on an http error. You are basing the answer on known libs like fetch or axios

Comment: @JulianKleine What will be the error code when your browser is unable to find a specific server?

Comment: I agree about the definition of status codes (?) .. but again .. who says that the implemenation of `publicInstance.get` would guarantee that the error is thrown?